# beautifulsoup: how to get indexes of elements in table headers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract the index of elements in the table headers, so that I can use the result to select the appropriate columns later on, in the body of the table. The columns vary in number but the ones I need remain constant in terms of their headings.

So I'd like to know that,for example, 'third' is index[2] in the headers of a table thus ‹th>first‹/th>‹th>second‹/th>‹th>third‹/th>‹th>fourth‹/th>‹th>fifth‹/th> 
I can then selectively choose the relevant ‹td>s in the following rows by selecting the ‹td>'s index number.

Here's my attempt:

```
#TRIAL TO GET INDEXES FROM TABLE HEADERS
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<table><thead><tr class="myClass"><th>A</th>'
'<th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr></thead></table>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find('table')

for hRow in table.find_all('th'):
hRow = hRow.index('A')
print hRow
```

Gives:

> ValueError: Tag.index: element not in tag

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find all headers and get the position of the header with the appropriate text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="myClass">
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

header_row = soup.select('table > thead > tr.myClass')[0]

headers = header_row.find_all('th')
header = header_row.find('th', text='A')
print headers.index(header)  # prints 0
```